# Realizar sort anidado dependiendo de una variable

Tags: javascript

Qusiera saber si existe alguna forma de realizar un sort anidado dependiendo de una variable que reciba una función para N casos de anidación. El valor que llega a la función puede ser de cualquier tipo. En este canso en particular se envia un string de cómo se debiese ver la anidación del objeto (Object.a.b.c.d... .n).

```
const orderValues (orderBy: string) => {
  console.debug(orderBy) //nes1.nest2.nest3... .nestN

  data.sort((dataSortA, dataSortB) => {
    if(dataSortA[orderBy] < dataSortB[orderBy]{
      return -1
    } else {
      return 1
    }
  }
}
```

Suponiendo que tengo la siguiente data

```
const data = [
  {
    nest1: {
      nest2: {
        nest3: {
          ...
          nestN: 3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    nest1: {
      nest2: {
        nest3: {
          ...
          nestN: 6
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    nest1: {
      nest2: {
        nest3: {
          ...
          nestN: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Debes agregar un ejemplo de entrada y de salida, y lo que llevas intentado para resolver el problema

Answer (score 0):

Una solución rápida a la que llegue, espero te sirva

```js
let data = [
  {
    nest1: {
      nest2: {
        nest3: {
          nestN: 3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    nest1: {
      nest2: {
        nest3: {
          nestN: 6
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    nest1: {
      nest2: {
        nest3: {
          nestN: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

function DeepValue(obj, path) {  
    for (var i=0, path=path.split('.'), len=path.length; i<len; i++){
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    };
    return obj;
}

function NestedSort(obj, path) {
   obj.sort((a, b) => DeepValue(a, path) - DeepValue(b, path));
}

NestedSort(data, 'nest1.nest2.nest3.nestN')


console.log(data)
```